# Dealing with Ghostery surrogates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Ghostery implements mock scripts (surrogates) so that pages don't fail on logic expecting tracking code.

In my case I had to write code that tracks asset and outbound clicks. The usual way to do that would be to check if the tracking code is loaded (in my case for `_gat` exposed by ga.js) but with surrogates this check would pass.

For some use cases that's fine and expected but we are dealing with links here. To ensure that the link is actually logged to GA I pushed a function to _gaq which (given that ga.js is loaded properly) would be executed.

With Ghostery that's not the case. I got links that would not trigger as the function with `window.location.href = url` would not be executed.

When I looked at the surrogate I found out it can change the location for me but I would have to do `_gaq.push(['_link', url])`.

I posted an [issue](https://getsatisfaction.com/ghostery/topics/surrogate_injection_does_not_mimic_tracker_behaviour_imho_it_should) and got a response that developers shouldn't bind functionality to third-party scripts. I get that and that's why before doing so I checked if `_gat` exists.

In the end I had to make a special case for Ghostery and attach their bizzare push to have links working with it.

You can check out the full implementation in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Zamber/4a162cbccf4b4e9eb641). If you want to reuse it and have compatibility with IE8 make sure to include a polyfill for `String.trim()`.

**How should I write custom tracking logic that does not rely in any way on the tracking code?**

Using `timeout` for changing the url is out of the question as it would potentially corrupt hits on slow connections.

Also, poking the `_gat` object is not a reliable way as it's bad to rely on third-party scripts.

Comment: Can you take a quick look at [my implementation](https://github.com/timver/jquery-ga/blob/master/jquery.analytics.js)? If you deny the `_gaq` object completely, you can still track/log anything you like ... If not, glad to hear why.

Comment: This would solve the problem of surrogating but it does not ensure that a hit get's logged if it navigates to an outbound site. I've stumbled to this http://www.axllent.org/docs/programming-tips/google-analytics/#automatically-track-outbound-links-using-async and it makes some sense. In that implementation logging an event does not interfere with any other functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers are currently building a feature that will solve this problem:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/navigator.sendBeacon

This won't widely implemented for a couple of months so stay tuned.  For now, just add a setTimeout(function(){location.href=url}, 100) to catch errors and still have the link work.